# Best practice for the placement of inline functions in C++

Tags: c++

Which is better for short functions (e.g. getters and setters)

1. In the class definition header file
2. At the end of the header file
3. In the source file (in this case should I use the `inline` keyword or `extern inline`?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't put inline functions in the source file (and have them used as inline) because their definition won't be available at the points the compiler needs them to inline the code.

Between the other two options, I tend to put one liners into the class definition and any others at the end of the header.

Comment: It really depends on where the inline functions are used.  If you have helper functions inside a source file, and they are short, it may be appropriate to declare them `inline` as a hint to the optimizer.  But I agree that class members should generally be defined as inline in the header file, or else non-inline in the source file.  Usually the size comes into it less than whether the implementation takes additional dependencies that you don't want to drag into the header file.

Answer (score 1):

> In the class definition header file

typically, unless your build times are more important (assuming that's not the case, based on the question). an exception follows

> At the end of the header file

rarely. i have when dealing with nasty templates, just to clean things up. the body is usually so small that it is not distracting, and this can expose implementation details (as a substitute for documentation, but i figure some people will rail me for that). example:

```
void compute() {
  assert(this->hasEnoughEnergyToCompute());
  ...computing
}
```

this approach can be good hygiene in some cases. i've actually used secondary files for this (a fourth option).

> In the source file

this option is ideal - if it's visible in every translation where you call it. otherwise, send it back to the header.

> in this case should I use the inline keyword or extern inline?

just 'inline'. in fact, your compiler probably declares methods inline implicitly. omit it altogether if all your required compilers support this.

Comment: No compiler declares methods inline implicitly (except for those declared inside a type definition).  Compilers can do inlining optimization on methods not declared inline, but the `inline` keyword, or absence thereof, still affects linkage.

Comment: +1 Good answer! I like that you brought up the build times, which I believe MANY c++ developers doesn't have a clue about. We have improved our link times several 100% by moving getters and setters from the header file to the source file.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to place it within the header file:

```
class A
{
private:
    int a;

public:
    const int getA() const { return a; }
    void setA(int val) { a = val; }
};
```

Just because the getX, setX functions are so tiny, they can easily fit in one line.

In general, my get and set methods typically are one line (Only on a few occasions did they require actual non-trivial code).

If you had some non-trivial code in there, like bounds checking or some extra calculations, I would advise against sticking it in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Where your coding guidelines says to put them.  There's no
absolute rule, but in general:

-- it's best to avoid inline functions until the profiler tells
    you you need them, and a lot of programming guidelines
    forbid them, and

-- it's usually best to avoid as much as possible in the class
    definition that isn't relevant to the actual interface; most
    coding guidelines suggest putting the implementation at the
    end of the header, or even in a separate file included from
    the header.

Having said that, if the function is so very simple that it fits
on the end of the line with the function declaration, I don't
think it hurts readability that much.